# How to create different objects depending on input?

Tags: python, django

What I have so far:

```
import app.models as models

if table_name ==  "Appliances":
    model = models.Appliances
elif table_name == "ArtsCraftsAndSewing":
    model = models.ArtsCraftsAndSewing
...

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    model = model(param1=row[column1], param2=row[column2], ...)
    model.save()
```

> TypeError: 'Appliances' object is not callable

Basically I'm trying to call `model = models.Appliances(param1=row[column1], param2=row[column2], ...)` except the specific object changes depending on input.

Edit: `Appliances` and `ArtsCraftsAndSewing` have the same parameters.

Comment: Will the **`table_name`** will be same as ***model class name*** always?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Yes, but I didn't want to parse the input string as python code because it'll introduce security issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By writing:

```
model = model(…)
```

in the second iteration, `model` no longer refers to the model, but now to an object of that model. You should change the name of the object, for example:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    model_object = model(param1=row[column1], param2=row[column2], …)
    # …
```

You might want to use a dictionary to do the mapping:

```
models = [models.Appliances, models.ArtsCraftsAndSewing]
model_dict = {
    m.__name__: m for m in models
}
model = model_dict[table_name]
```

Comment: Oooooh okay, so I actually just replaced the selected model class. It works for the first iteration, but not the rest. I was trying to condense the number of variables, but that was the wrong condensation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`getattr()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) here,

```
from app_name import models

table_name = 'Appliances' # or something else
ModelKlass = getattr(models, table_name)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    model_instance = ModelKlass(param1=row[column1], param2=row[column2], ...)
```

**Note:** I assume `table_name` will be the Django model name.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a dictionary of all the different model types and pass your inputs as keys:

```
model_types = dict('appliances' = Appliances, 'arts_crafts_and_sewing' = ArtsCraftsAndSewing)

your_object = model_types[type](param1=arg1, param2=arg2, ...) // here `type` is your input which you can enter via some form or whatever.
```